# How to export the selected results of a JSON query to a list when clicking a button

Tags: jquery, json, list, getjson

I'm making an application,where I query the lastFM api, query the top artists and searching with the help of regex. The results are properly displayed using a .getJSON method. Next to each artist, I have added a button so that I can add the selected artist to a list. Now I want to have a separate list below so that when I click "Add to list", my lists gets populated with the artists' name. Unfortunately, when I try to append a list, the var.name variable is not appended to the list. There is an image attached.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() { //when key is pressed in search bar
        var searchTerm = $(this).val(); //value obtained from the search bar
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i"); //regular expression search
        $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getTopArtists&user=test&api_key=4a9f5581a9cdf20a699f540ac52a95c9&limit=100&format=json&callback=?", function(json) { //get the json file 
            var output = "<ul id='result'>";
            $.each(json.topartists.artist, function(key, val) {
                if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) { //search for the data in the json file
                    output += '<td>';
                    output += '<h4>' + val.name + ' ' + '<button>Add to list</button>' + '</h4>';
                    output += '</td>';
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("button").click(function() {
                            $("ol").append("<li>" + val.name + "' <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'>×</a></li>");
                        });
                        $(document).on("click", "a.remove", function() {
                            $(this).parent().remove();
                        });
                    });
                }
            }); //end each
            output += "</ul>";
            $('#update').html(output); //output result to the update div

        });
    });

});
```

My html list is something like that

```
<ol>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</ol>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey there ^^ Consider choosing a framework (Backbone, Angular, any React flavour) instead of spaghetti jQuery.

Comment: By appending a NEW event handler with each and  `$(document).ready(function() {
                        $("button").click(function() {` you demonstrate the need to study and understand event handlers.  Note that is also hits the DOM every time you do that.

Comment: Hi Mark, You're right about the $(document).ready(function() { $("button").click(function(). :) Your suggestion works ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() { //when key is pressed in search bar
        var searchTerm = $(this).val(); //value obtained from the search bar
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i"); //regular expression search
        $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getTopArtists&user=test&api_key=4a9f5581a9cdf20a699f540ac52a95c9&limit=100&format=json&callback=?", function(json) { //get the json file 
            var output = $('<ul id="result"></ul>');
            $.each(json.topartists.artist, function(key, val) {
                if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) { //search for the data in the json file
                    var row = $("<li></li>");
                    var heading = $('<h4>' + val.name + '</h4>');
                    var addButton = $('<button>Add to list</button>')
                        .click(function() {
                            var newRow = $('<li>' + val.name + '</li>');
                            var removeButton = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove">×</a>')
                                .click(function() {
                                    $(this).parent().remove();
                                });
                            newRow.append(removeButton);

                            $("ol").append(newRow);
                        }):

                    heading.append(addButton);
                    row.append(heading);

                    output.append(row);
                }
            }); //end each
            $('#update').empty().append(output); //output result to the update div
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the event handler out of the loop and slight adjustment to the markup to make this work faster/better:

Markup:

```
<ol id="mynewthingslist">
</ol>
```

Revised:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() { //when key is pressed in search bar
    var searchTerm = $(this).val(); //value obtained from the search bar
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i"); //regular expression search
    $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getTopArtists&user=test&api_key=4a9f5581a9cdf20a699f540ac52a95c9&limit=100&format=json&callback=?", function(json) { //get the json file 
      var output = "<ul id='result'>";
      $.each(json.topartists.artist, function(key, val) {
        if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) { //search for the data in the json file
          output += '<td>';
          output = output + '<h4>' + val.name + ' ' + '<button class="add-to-list" data-name="' + val.name + '">Add to list</button>' + '</h4>';
          output += '</td>';
        }
      }); //end each
      output += "</ul>";
      $('#update').html(output); //output result to the update div
    });
  });
  $('#update').on('click', 'button.add-to-list', function() {
    $("#mynewthingslist").append("<li>" + $(this).data('name') + "' <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'>×</a></li>");
  });
  $("#mynewthingslist").on("click", "a.remove", function() {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
  });
});
```